# How to compute $||T||$?

Tags: real-analysis, operator-theory, fourier-series

for the function  $f \in L^2 ([-\pi,\pi])$ define the map $ T: L^2([-\pi, \pi]) \to R $ as $T(f)=a_1+b_1 $ if the Fourier series of $f$ is of the form

$f $ ~ $a_0 +\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_ncos(nx)+b_nsin(nx)) $ by finding function $h \in L^2 ([-\pi,\pi])$ so that $T(f)=\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)h(x)dx $

$ a_0:=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\,\mathrm d x\\ a_n:=\frac1{\pi }\int_{-\pi }^\pi f(x)\cos(nx)\,\mathrm d x\\
b_n:=\frac1{\pi }\int_{-\pi }^\pi f(x)\sin(nx)\,\mathrm d x$

and eventually found $h(x)=\frac1{\pi }(\cos (x)+\sin(x)) $

how can i compute $ ||T||$ ? I tried to calculate, however got big integral and got confused, is there anyway to nicely compute it?

Comment: by cauchy schwarz, $|T(f)| \leq ||f||_{L^2}||h||_{L^2}$ so that $||T|| = ||h||_{L^2}$, which you can work out.

Comment: Dear George, so the integral ||T|| is going to integral of  the h(x) squared, right? I am sorry if i am asking trivial questions.

Comment: thats exactly it, then all to the power of one half

Comment: Dear George! $ (\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(h(x))^2dx)^{1/2}=(1/\pi^2 \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(1+sin(2x)dx)^{1/2}=\sqrt(2/\pi)$ I got something like this

Comment: sorry, I miscalculated, it should be 0

Comment: $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}$ is right